# Are there active rectifiers that consume whole sine wave?

Tags: rectifier, bridge-rectifier

Basic rectifiers use mostly the top of the sine amplitude (when the sine gets above the capacitor's voltage), which results in the sine amplitude tops being cut. Are there rectifiers that consume constant current from an AC source, thus not affecting the sine?

Comment: What you are looking for is called an Active Power Factor Correction (PFC) rectifier.

Comment: consuming constant current would affect the sine. The current should be proportional to the sine voltage.

Comment: For an alternaitve approach (starting with a 3 phase supply) search for "12 pulse rectifier" or more generally, polyphase rectifier

Comment: The reason they only use the top of the sine wave is not because of the rectifier per-se, but because of the large capacitor after the rectifier. The situation can be improved if the rectifier does not have a large capacitor on it. As others have said, the concept of power-factor correction incorporates something like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. This is called Active Power Factor Correction.

It works by using a rectifier, then a boost converter with a specialized control chip to actively control the current flow. The inner control loop makes the current proportional to the voltage (so the device looks like a resistor) and the outer control loop adjusts the resistance to make sure the device gets enough power.

Since it's a boost converter, the output is a DC voltage higher than the AC peak voltage. Energy is stored in a big capacitor which is recharged each cycle.

Answer (score 0):

putting an inductor after a bridge rectifier can cause a wider conduction angle and improve power factor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frYPX4.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: You can also add inductance to the AC side to reduce the current peaks into a filter capacitor.

Comment: putting the inductor before the rectifier limits it is discontinuous curren mode, but I guess that could be useful if you also need short-circuit protection or want to save money by having only one magnetic part. (where the inductor could be designed into the transfotmer - like in microwave ovens)